# Angular 2: Property injection instead of constructor injection

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Can I do this:

```
export class BaseComponent {
protected config: IConfig;

@Inject(AppConfig) protected appConfig: AppConfig;

constructor() 
{ 
    this.config = this.appConfig.getConfig();    
}
```

instead of this:

```
export class BaseComponent {
config: IConfig;

constructor(
    private appConfig: AppConfig,
    ) 
{ 
    this.config = appConfig.getConfig();    
}
```

The goal is to simplify the constructor signature, so all child component to not need to specify appConfig in their constructor. So the components that inherits from BaseComponent to look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sport-templates',
    templateUrl: 'templates.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'templates.component.scss' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SportTemplates extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
```

instead like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sport-templates',
    templateUrl: 'templates.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'templates.component.scss' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SportTemplates extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(appConfig: AppConfig) {
        super(appConfig);
     }
```

Comment: Have you found out the best solution for constructor injection?

Comment: I found answer of my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461852/angular-2-inject-service-manually Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
myService: MyService = this.injector.get(MyService);
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}
```

The Injector is in @angular/core

Comment: While it works, it doesn't look like the true way. More like a Service Locator pattern. Though I have to admit that difference is subtle.

Answer (score 2):

This is now (since Angular v14) possible to do via the `inject` [function](https://angular.io/api/core/inject#usage-notes) from `@angular/core`. It behaves the same as the decorator and can be used on property initializers:

```
@Directive()
export abstract class BaseComponent {
    protected appConfig = inject(AppConfig)
}
```

Therefore, you don't need to call `super(appConfig)` any more.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it. **Injectable service** will e injected when the constructor is called.

> The goal is to simplify the constructor signature.

There is no need to simplify constructor signature. For readability you can write them in multiple lines.

> so all child component to not need to specify appConfig in their
>   constructor

In your case only classes that inherit your class will access that. But if you mean child component those ones which are used in your component, they can't access variables in parent component. You need to pass them.

**UPDATED**

Your `this.config` is always visible in inherited components. There is no need to again inject `appConfig` in the `SportTemplates` component.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added a bit clarification in my question.

Comment: Now I have a BaseComponent which is inhereted by 19 child components. BaseComponent needs a service, to define a method which will get inhereted. Now I need to "send this service via" constructors of all 19 children. I guess that's what he meant with 'so all child components not need to specify "..." in their constructors'

Comment: If you have inheritance, you need to provide from child constructors to the parent constructor via `super()` call.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan of course, therefore the 'Property injection instead of constructor injection' question, so that I don't have to.