# Angular UT component with static injector

Tags: angular, jasmine, ts-jest

I have quite a big class hierarchy in my project and I had to extract much of the duplicated code to parent class that would be extended, having children and even grandchildren. Parent class -> child class -> child of child class. Something like this. Trying to avoid duplicating constructors and super() call I used Injector.create({options}) in the parent class to inject some of the required services. The problem is now that all my tests are failing with TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.
Here is what I have:

```
export abstract class ParentClass implements OnInit {
   protected router: Router;
   
   protected constructor() {
      this.router = AppModuleServices.injector.get(Router);
   }
}
```

Now the AppModuleServices is just a wrapping class around the injector in order to have it used in my whole project.

```
export class AppModuleServices {
  static injector: Injector;
}
```

I'm setting the static injector in the app's module like this:

```
export class SomeModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppModuleServices.injector = this.injector;
  }
}
```

Everything works just fine, it's correctly doing it's job but the UT are all failing.

I've tried [Angular 2 instantiate global injector in parent in Karma Jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817389/4645310) but with no success
Does anyone know what is to be done on the spec side to have this work?

Thank you

**UPDATE**:
After debugging the tests I found that actually the error is:

```
ReferenceError: AppModuleServices is not defined
```

**Info**:
AppModuleServices is not actually a module. It's just an exported class, if it matters. I've tried to put the injector into the actual app module, but trying to use it lower in the hierarchy creates a circular dependency. But still, as it works while running the application, I don't think that is the problem, something about mocking the injector should be my solution.

Comment: not answering the question, but to avoid chained constructors and super calls, you can define parents as abstract classes without constructors, with services as abstract, protected members. Then you need to inject them only in the "real" component class

Comment: I see, but that's one of the issue I had. Quite a lot of services in many components, so SonarQube was complaining about duplicated code for all the constructors.

Comment: Quite often such an error is a result of circular dependencies in your code. Hard to tell for sure without seeing the actual code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you share unit test code?

Comment: it seems like `SomeModule`  module is not imported to your unit test. But Yes unit test code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but in my case instead of Modules constructor I was setting the `AppModuleServices.injector` in side factory for `APP_INITIALIZER`. Anyway the effect was same, while running UT as the service locator was not set.

My solution was to set the service locator in side the *main* file of test bulter, *test.ts*.

```
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
AppModuleServices.injector = TestBed.inject(Injector);
```

For me even this solved the issue of service locator instance of Injector. But the instance of services injected by DI via constructor was different. Thus a new instance of service was created for each `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` call.

To solve this I created a mock module where I provided for the required service.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useValue: AppModuleServices.injector.get(MyService) }
  ]
})
export MockModuleStub {
  // required initiation if any
}
```

This module can be imported in the spec so the service instance is referred from service locator's Injector instead of creating new.