# typescript: invoke constructor with injected parameters implicity

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, constructor, angular5

How to create an instance of Point in that way:

```
let npoint = new Point();
```

Point's constructor requires an argument (differs), which should be injected.

```
import { DoCheck, KeyValueDiffers, KeyValueDiffer } from '@angular/core';

export class GsPoint {

  uuid: string;

  differ: any;
  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = this.differs.find({}).create();
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    const change = this.differ.diff(this);
    if (change) {
      change.forEachChangedItem(item => {
        console.log('item changed', item);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is an ordinary class (not a component or a directive) then you can not inject the `KeyValueDiffers` service like we do at Component level or at module level.

1.) You need to

- add @Injectable() to GsPoint and
- provide GsPoint like providers: [GsPoint ] in a component or NgModule.

When you then inject GsPoint somewhere, a KeyValueDiffers instance gets passed to GsPoint when it is instantiated by DI (before it is injected the first time).

2.) An alternative approach is to configure a custom injector like

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) { 
   let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([KeyValueDiffers]);
   let childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders,this.injector);

  let myDiffer : KeyValueDiffers= childInjector.get(KeyValueDiffers);
```

}

This way `myDiffer` will be a `KeyValueDiffers` instance, instantiated by Angulars DI, and `myDiffer` will be injected to `GSPoint` when instantiated.

But if you want to do it in that way then in component or in service where ever you use this class you have to pass the `this.myDiffer` instance of `KeyValueDiffers` service. (Note:- `KeyValueDiffers` must be injected in that component from which you create the object of this GsPoint Class)

```
 import {KeyValueDiffers , Component  } from '@angular/core';
 import {GSPoint} from '../gspoint/gspoint.ts';

 @Component({
    'selector': 'app-sample',
    'templateUrl':'sample.html',
    'styleUrl': 'sample.css'   
  })
 export class Sample {

   constructor(private diff: KeyValueDiffers){

     }
 ngOnInit(){
     let gsPoint = new GSPoint(this.dff); // this is how you can create object
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is some kind of service locator.
Generally I would not recommend using this approach because you are hiding the class dependencies from the caller and makes testing potentially harder.

[If you still want to implement your way, check out this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42462579/4673570)