# Inject service after constructor finished

Tags: angular, typescript, service, httpclient

I wrote a service to access the spotify api.
In the constructor this service should get the access token.
Therefore I call subscribe method on an Observable.

The problem with that:

The service gets injected into my main component.
There I call methods of this service to receive data from spotify api.
I think the problem is that the access token is not yet received before the first request to the api tries to use it.

How can I do so, that the service only gets injected after the constructor finished getting the access token?

Comment: You can't do that. Have your service treat the access token as an observable, and chain your requests onto that.

Comment: If delaying the page load until the access token is available is also an option (i.e if the token is absolutely crucial to your application) you can also consider using a [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the instance of a service but not injected through the constructor you may want to use injector.get method to get the instance. Something like -

```
const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationService);
```

For more details/example please refer -

https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a, [Inject a service manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461852/inject-a-service-manually),
https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get

Comment: This will not solve their problem as there will still be a race condition between the API request and the dependency resolution even if the service is initially provided in root.