# In Angular, can you inject into a super class without passing it from extended components?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to get the PLATFORM_ID on my super class but I'd rather not have to pass it from all classes extending it. I tried making it optional but it just came back as undefined.

This is in my base class

```
 constructor(
    public bucketType: 'quote' | 'list' | 'quote_cart' | 'cart',
    public http: HttpClient,
    public gaService: GaService,
    public gtmService: GtmDataLayerService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId?: string
) {
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461852/inject-a-service-manually

Answer (score 1):

Your service could look like:

**some.service.ts**

```
let platform: string;

export function setPlatform(value) {
  platform = value;
}

@Injectable(...)
export class SomeService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(platform);
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is to set platform variable only once:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { setPlatform } from './some.service';

@NgModule(...)
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId?: string) {
    setPlatform(platformId);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is prolly what I should have done to begin with. Not sure if it is worth the refactor but I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's up to you what to choose. I only show you simplest option