# How to manually inject dependency in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

In angular we can manually access and inject dependencies using the built in `Injector` class. By which you can access Injectables and Inject them without actually passing them in the constructor. Basically I want to inject a service to another service without passing it as an arg to the constructor.

This is the angular equivalent [Inject a service manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461852/inject-a-service-manually)

I wanted to achieve similar thing in nestjs

Note : The service to be injected also has a dependency, so I can't just instantiate it

Answer (score 9):

I believe what you're looking for is Nest's [ModuleRef](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) class, where you can do something like the following:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CatsService implements OnModuleInit {
  private service: Service;
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.service = this.moduleRef.get(Service);
  }
}
```

Where `Service` should actually be the class you are wanting to inject.

Comment: Just a remark, that if you want to resolve a dependency from other than current module, you need to also pass { strict: false } as 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Inject('token') should work as you expected

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService<T> {
  @Inject('HTTP_OPTIONS')
  private readonly httpClient: T;
}
```

ref: https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection